# Memory release after joblib.Parallel [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, scope

Stuck with the [issue](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/167) with memory consumption - after running joblib's Parallel, deleting results and gc.collect() -ing I still have increased memory (checking by htop for process line). Found no way to free memory back. To broaden **yangqch** [answer](https://github.com/joblib/joblib/issues/167#issuecomment-60874719) I use such code to isolate memory for parallel computations:

Imports -

```
import multiprocessing as mp
n_cores = mp.cpu_count()
import time
import datetime
from sklearn.externals.joblib import Parallel, delayed
import sklearn
from functools import partial
import pickle
```

joblib progress bar -

```
class BatchCompletionCallBack(object):
    # Added code - start
    global total_n_jobs
    global jobs_start_time
    # Added code - end
    def __init__(self, dispatch_timestamp, batch_size, parallel):
        self.dispatch_timestamp = dispatch_timestamp
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.parallel = parallel

    def __call__(self, out):
        self.parallel.n_completed_tasks += self.batch_size
        this_batch_duration = time.time() - self.dispatch_timestamp

        self.parallel._backend.batch_completed(self.batch_size,
                                           this_batch_duration)
        self.parallel.print_progress()
        # Added code - start
        progress = self.parallel.n_completed_tasks / total_n_jobs
        elapsed = int((time.time() - jobs_start_time) / self.parallel.n_completed_tasks * (total_n_jobs - self.parallel.n_completed_tasks))
        print(
            "\r[{:50s}] {:.1f}% - Elapsed time {} ".format(
                '#' * int(progress * 50)
                , progress*100
                , datetime.timedelta(seconds=elapsed))
            , end="", flush=True)
        if self.parallel.n_completed_tasks == total_n_jobs:
            print('\n')
        # Added code - end
        if self.parallel._original_iterator is not None:
            self.parallel.dispatch_next()

sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel.BatchCompletionCallBack = BatchCompletionCallBack
```

Parallel wrapper -

```
def parallel_wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
    global total_n_jobs, jobs_start_time
    total_n_jobs = len(args[0])
    jobs_start_time = time.time()

    if kwargs:
        mapfunc = partial(func, **kwargs)
    else:
        mapfunc = func

    with open('file.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(Parallel(n_jobs=n_cores)(map(delayed(mapfunc), *args)), file)
    print('Operating time - ', datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(time.time() - jobs_start_time)))
```

Class to use in 'with' construction -

```
class isolate:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def run(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.p = mp.Process(target=self.func, args=(func, *args), kwargs=kwargs)
        self.p.start()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.p.join()
```

Example -

```
def dummy(i, keyword_argument=None):
    return (i.shape, keyword_argument)

import numpy as np
tmp = np.ones((5,5))

with isolate(parallel_wrapper) as isolated:
    isolated.run(dummy, [tmp, tmp], keyword_argument=2)

with open('file.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    tmp = pickle.load(file)

tmp

import importlib
importlib.reload(sklearn.externals.joblib.parallel)
```

So questions are:

- is there an easier way
- how to make local variable 'total_n_jobs' from 'parallel_wrapper' viewable in 'BatchCompletionCallBack' without 'global'
- any improvements